# License of QtCore in Qt 5.6: LGPL v2.1 or LGPL v3?

Tags: licensing, lgpl

In the headers of QtCore 5.6 it says:

```
-- clip --

** GNU Lesser General Public License Usage
** Alternatively, this file may be used under the terms of the GNU Lesser
** General Public License version 2.1 or version 3 as published by the Free
** Software Foundation and appearing in the file LICENSE.LGPLv21 and
** LICENSE.LGPLv3 included in the packaging of this file.

-- clip --
```

Does this now mean that I can still use QtCore from Qt 5.6 under LGPL v2.1 ? At least this is how I interpret "or".

On their web page they say that QtCore would be LGPL v3 from 5.4 onward, but it's not what's in the actual headers..?

Comment: That certainly looks like it's available under your choice of either to me. One thing I'd be wary of, though, is that "QtCore" may consist of many files, and possibly only some of them include the LGPLv2.1 option. In that case (N.B.: which I cannot verify as true or false), you could only use the sum total under the LGPLv3 option common to all files.